# Pass an array from vba to c++ dll then back to vba

Tags: c++, excel, vba, dll

i have a c++ dll that contains a class and some functions that work with the class 
the subroutine that i'm trying to use takes, 1 array as parameter ( a pointer )
the array contains some values and these will be modified by the subroutine

so basicaly my subroutine looks like this

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub foo Lib "Path to my Dll" (ByRef Inp As Double)
```

the thing is, when i call my sub like this

```
Dim Inp(100) As Double '100 is a test value



Call foo(Inp(1))
```

i get error 49 Bad DLL calling convention

my c++ routine looks like this just for testing

```
void EditArray(double *Arr){
      Arr[1]++;
   }
```

can someone help me finding what is causing this error please :(

Comment: Yes, Microsoft can. Care to lookup "error 49 Bad DLL calling convention".

Comment: i looked it up before posting and i can't see where i'm matching any of the criteria  that is supposed to cause this error

Comment: You should have said it. Is StdCall in force ?

Comment: 32 or 64bit? 64bits no longer require stdcall. you can try something like __declspec(dllexport) void foo in the header file...